# Can't close modal when I click outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm building my first website and I'm having trouble with the click outside modal (nav) to close using javascript.

HTML:

```
<nav>
                <img src="/Images/ham.png" alt="toggle menu" class="menu" id="menu"> 
                </a>


                <ul class="show-desktop hide-mobile" id="nav">
                    <li id="exit" class="exit-btn hide-desktop">
                        <img src="/Images/exit.svg" alt="exit menu">
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="work.html">work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    var exit = document.getElementById('exit');



    menu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    exit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        nav.classList.add('hide-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });



    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == nav) {
        nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (event.target != nav){
        nav.classlist.add('hide-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
        }
}

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.hide-mobile{
    right: -400px;
    transition: linear .5s;
}

nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 60%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgb(36,41,44);
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 7;
    padding-top: 3em;
    right: 0px;
    transition: ease-out .5s;
}
```

I got the first set of javascript code (menu and exit button functions) from a tutorial and now I'm trying to add the close on outside click function. I've added a window.onclick function to show the nav modal when click on nav and hide it when click outside nav but it wont close when I click outside nav.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Add a click listener on the document itself, when this click is dispatched check if the target (element which has been clciked on) is not the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
var exit = document.getElementById('exit');

menu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

exit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    nav.classList.add('hide-mobile');
    e.preventDefault();
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target != nav){
        nav.classList.add('hide-mobile');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

this can solve your problem with your way.

Comment: I tried this but then the menu doesn't open at all.

Comment: Ok I need to add    e.stopPropagation();  under menu as well didn't realise that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

In window.onclick function, you should check is modal open? You can add a specific class when the modal is active and if it is active you can close it.