# close html5 dialog by clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, dialog

I have implemented several html5 dialogs in a web page. I want to enable the user to **click outside of the dialog in order to close it**, instead of cluttering up the dialog with a close button or requiring an {escape} keypress. Many queries on this matter are for exotic js libraries but I want to use plain JS not jquery.

## JS

```
// HALFHIDE
function openHALFHIDEdialog() {
var dialogHALFHIDEsource_O = document.getElementById("S-HALFHIDE");
dialogHALFHIDEsource_O.showModal();
}

function closeHALFHIDEdialog() {
var dialogHALFHIDEsource_C = document.getElementById("S-HALFHIDE");
dialogHALFHIDEsource_C.close(); }
```

## HTML

```
<!-- S. HALFHIDE -->
<div class = "generic_dialog_container">
<dialog class = "generic dialog" id = "S-HALFHIDE">

<p>Blah blah blah</p>

</dialog></div>
<!-- END S HALFHIDE -->
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't close modal when I click outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426848/cant-close-modal-when-i-click-outside-of-it)

Comment: Given that my div class and dialog class, a simple one-liner solution for detecting a click outside of those elements and invoking a close function is the cleanest most succinct solution. Writing a dozen or more lines of JS isn't really needed, is it?

Comment: The problem you run into, verlager, is that the `dialog` element takes up the entirety of the window when it is in its open state.  Therefore, **all clicks inside of the web page, after the modal is open, register as a click on the dialog element**, which explains  You'd be in a FAR better position to write your own modal, given that the `dialog`element is not even supported in some still relevant browsers such as Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close the new html <dialog> tag by clicking on its ::backdrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864259/how-to-close-the-new-html-dialog-tag-by-clicking-on-its-backdrop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This caused me to look into the `dialog` element quite a bit. Just a forewarning, as I mentioned in my comments, the `dialog` element is lacking in support as its not supported by Safari or Firefox.

Here is a REPL you can run that contains the solution: https://replit.com/@heyitsmarcus/Dialog#index.html

But, I did find a solution here that works here on Stack Overflow: [How to close the new html <dialog> tag by clicking on its ::backdrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864259/how-to-close-the-new-html-dialog-tag-by-clicking-on-its-backdrop)

```
dialog.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var rect = dialog.getBoundingClientRect();
    var isInDialog=(rect.top <= event.clientY && event.clientY <= rect.top + rect.height
      && rect.left <= event.clientX && event.clientX <= rect.left + rect.width);
    if (!isInDialog) {
        dialog.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a very good solution because it references the dialog itself instead of making me write other code that references by ID 150 X.

Comment: You should never have to do that. Even outside of this dialog element, always use classes to group together your elements. They are powerful!